# Как удалить элемент из выпадающего списка с помощью jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, php

Добрый день. Прошу помощи в решении проблемы.

Есть форма редактирования меню:

```
$menu =  '<select id="my_select" name="menu_text">
            <option selected>' . $row["menu"] . '</option>
            <option>1</option>                     
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>' ;
```

В элемент `<option selected>` подгружается  значение из базы данных (ранее записанное туда одно из значений `option` 1, 2, 3 или 4). В итоге выпадающий список имеет вид, например:

```
3 (выбранное поле)
3 
1
2
3
4
```

Задача: каким-либо способом убрать повтор элемента в списке, если он уже является загруженным в качестве `<option selected>`, т. е. в приведенном примере добиться вида:

```
3 (выбранное поле)
3 
1
2
4    // пункт 3 отсутствует
```

Есть `var a=$("#my_select :selected").html();` 
Как произвести сравнение с оставшимися элементами и удалить один из них при совпадении значения? Может быть, подход к решению должен быть другим?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так не получается?

```
<?php

$menu = '<select id="my_select" name="menu_text">';
foreach([1,2,3,4] as $item) {
    $selected = ($item == $row["menu"]) ? 'selected="selected"' ? '';
    $menu .= '<option '.$selected.'>'.$item.'</option>';
}
$menu .= '</select>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, чуть-чуть иначе выводить:

```
$menu =  '<select id="my_select" name="menu_text">

            <option'if ($row["menu"]==1){echo "selected" }'>1</option>                     
            <option'if ($row["menu"]==2){echo "selected" }'>2</option>
            <option'if ($row["menu"]==3){echo "selected" }'>3</option>
            <option'if ($row["menu"]==4){echo "selected" }'>4</option>
          </select>' ;
```

А по правильному - у тебя должен быть массив с разделами меню, ты бежишь по нему и создаешь HTML-код выпадающего списка (как я понял, вы работаешь без MVC):

```
$menu_arr = array("0","1","2","3","4");
$selected = 3;
$menu_html = "<select><option></option>";
foreach($menu_arr as $key=>$value){
 $menu_html .="<option ";
 $menu_html .= ($value==$selected) ? "selected >$value" : ">$value";
 $menu_html .="</option>";
}
$menu_html .="</select>";
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Сделал по принципу второго примера, все заработало.